# Group Noun with singular verb vs Group Noun with plural verb— What's the difference?

Tags: difference, semantics

The government has made up its mind. Vs The government have made up their minds.

Semantically,What is the difference in meaning ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no substantial difference in meaning.

In American English only the first is considered correct grammar.

In British English you could use either, with the nuance of considering the group as a single unit, or as multiple individuals.  In many examples it you can think if you are talking about the group or the individuals in the group:

> My family are coming for dinner (There are several individual people coming)

> My family is large (The group is large, but not necessarily the individuals in it)